# i am using facebook SDK 3.0 i have to get profile picture of user login. Here is the code I use

Tags: android, facebook

i am using facebook SDK 3.0 i have to get profile picture of user login. Here is the code I use

```
public Bitmap getUserPic(String userID) {

    String imageURL;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?type=small";

    try {

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageURL).getContent());

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.d("TAG", "Loading Picture FAILED");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: I want the image from Facebook and store it on my server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the profile picture  in an imageview use simply this code with your userId

```
ProfilePictureView  image=((ProfilePictureView)mMovableListView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)) ;
image.setProfileId(userid);
```